# Are bluetooth LE connections authenticated on Android?

Tags: android, bluetooth-lowenergy, bluetooth-gatt, cc-mode

I am having an issue where I cannot communicate with Bluetooth LE devices if my Android 8 phone, with common criteria mode enabled. When common criteria mode is disabled, everything works as expected.

However, when I use my Android 6 phone with common criteria mode enabled, I have no issue.

I came across this [link](https://docs.samsungknox.com/whitepapers/knox-platform/common-criteria-mode.htm?Highlight=bluetooth) that states that common criteria mode "prevents non-authenticated Bluetooth connections"

So what I am thinking is bluetooth LE connections are not authenticated, and BLE will never work with common criteria mode until samsung and knox work something out.

I have tried a 3 different BLE devices on 3 different apps, and the behavior is always the same, the devices work great with common criteria mode off, but they don't work with common criteria mode on.

I even made a test app, and when common criteria mode is enabled, my GATT callbacks immediately return error 133 "GATT_ERROR" and newState 0, "DISCONNECTED".

Comment: Well BLE connections must always be non-secure at the time a connection is established. Then a procedure can make the unencrypted link encrypted. So it feels like their design is broken or they forgot to mention the details how it works.

Comment: I was thinking that was the case. If their whole idea is to keep all Bluetooth connections 100% secure, then they would have to block all BLE connections.

Comment: Emil, would you know of a outside of the box way around the OS for BLE connections, or anyway of by-passing this? Like any ideas or theories?

Comment: Not unless you root it.

Comment: Would it be possible to use a custom BLE stack in lieu of the built-in stack without rooting the phone? We are getting desperate for a creative solution.

Comment: No, since it's a system thing.